# Example for System Given Hilbert Space

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space

What are some concrete examples of physical systems such that their corresponding Hilbert space is given by $\mathbb{C}$?

Also, what is the physical difference between a system whose corresponding Hilbert space is $\mathbb{C}\otimes\mathbb{C}$ and $\mathbb{C}\times\mathbb{C}$? (tensor product vs. Cartesian product)?

Comment: Do you mean that every complex number is an actual state? Do you demand to have the physical system represent the algebraic structure of ℂ? If you don't demand either, then ℂ is equivalent to a two dimensional vector space and one could identify that with the coordinates of a free point particle in two dimensions, but that is not what you mean, right? If you are looking at a subset of ℂ (complex numbers with magnitude 1), then it's spin states, I would say, but that's also trivial.

Answer (score 0):

The Hilbert space of quantum mechanics arises from considering irreducible representations of the C*-algebra of observables. When the C*-algebra of a physical system is commutative all its irreducible representations are one dimensional and therefore the corresponding Hilbert space is $\mathbb C$. Hence any classical physical system is associated to the Hilbert space $\mathbb C$.

The tensor product $\mathbb C\otimes\mathbb C$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb C$. One can think of this situation as the direct product of two classical systems, which still behaves classically.

The cartesian product gives $\mathbb C^2$, which hosts an irreducible representation of the Fermi oscillator, i.e. a system with just two states: vacuum/occupied.

Comment: The dimension of $\mathbb C\otimes\mathbb C$ is one and it is easy to see that indeed $\mathbb C\otimes\mathbb C$ **IS** $\mathbb C$...

Comment: I suggest you review your knowledge of the tensor product :)